# Using antlr3 with python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, antlr, antlr4, antlr3

I have a python project I wrote in python 2.7 with antlr3,

now, when python are killing python2 I want to convert it into a python3 project, which is easy using 2to3 library.

when I try to run `pip3 install antlr3-python-runtime` I get an error because antlr3 does not support python3, so I need to install antlr4, which I did.

the problem is that now I need to change the code to be compatible with antlr4, but the code has thousands of lines, so I can't go line by line.

Is there a way to convert antlr3 project to antlr4 project or to use antlr3 in python3?

Comment: Is the grammar thousands of lines, or is the code that uses the parse/syntax tree  thousands of lines?

Comment: the code itself

Comment: Yeah, then it's harder. Anyway, my answer still applies: manual work.

Comment: I hope you're wrong, because otherwise i'm screwed

Comment: Screwed? Maybe not. Though ANTLR 4 is different from ANTLR 3 in many ways, migration is not as difficult as you imagined (I did that for my commercial product a few years ago). The "thousands of lines" might even be running without much modification if you know what I mean. However, such migration requires manual work and experience so you'd better hire someone if you don't plan to do that yourself.

Comment: "I hope you're wrong", don't hold your breath while waiting for another answer :)

Comment: Btw, if it's an opensource project, you could link it in your question: it might generate some traffic and perhaps someone knowledgeable of ANTLR might chip in.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert antlr3 project to antlr4 project or to use antlr3 in python3?

I know of no tool that does this. You'll have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

ANTLR3 is supported in Python3

The package in Debian is named `python3-antlr3`

Alternatively you can find it here: https://gitrepos.estec.esa.int/taste/taste-setup/-/tree/feature_buster/antlr/antlr3_python3_runtime_3.4